# Using NSRegularExpression to validate only String or Number

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

ok in IPad i have 2 textfield one accepting only string
and other textField accepts integer only.

so can i validate them using NSRegularExpression ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RegExKit library

```
[_yourString isMatchedByRegex:@"\\d+"];
```

Comment: What's the point of this answer? (The OP specifically states NSRegularExpression.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use *NSPredicate* to serve your purpose here.

**To match numbers:**

```
NSString *number = @"12345";
NSString *regex = @"[0-9]*";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
BOOL match = [predicate evaluateWithObject:number]);
```

**To match strings:**

```
NSString *string = @"Hello";
NSString *regex = @"[a-z]*";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[C] %@", regex];
BOOL match = [predicate evaluateWithObject:string]);
```

In the above regex `@"[a-z]*";` I've omitted the capitalized characters `"A-Z"` because I've used `MATCHES[C]` in the predicate in which `C` stands for the case-insensitivity.